# Selenium with JS how to count child elements inside parent

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I got the following HTML structure:

```
<ul id="test">
   <li><div><span>name one</span></div></li>
   <li><div><span>name two</span></div></li>
   <li><div><span>name three</span></div></li>
   <li><div><span>name four</span></div></li>
</ul>
```

My first question is how could I get the number of li tags inside using Selenium.
In cypress is simple as:

```
cy.get('#test').children().should('have.length', 4)
```

And my second question is:
How could I get the nth-child inside this ul?
I tried by doing this:

```
const firstName = await d.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@id, 'test')]/li/div/span")).getText()
```

Here I got the first li text, but how could I get the text of the remaining lists inside?

```
const secondManualName = await d.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul[contains(@id, 'test')]>li:nth-child(2)>div>span")).getText()
```

In the above line of code it is throwing an error, that there is not such a function. I cannot understand why the selenium documentation is so incomplete. I will appreciate if you recommend me some good website for selenium with JS( with some nice examples ).

Answer (score 0):

To get the *nth* `<li>` *child* inside the `<ul>` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  ul#test li:nth-child(n) > div > span
  where, n = 2,3,4 etc.
  ```
- Effective line of code:

  ```
  await driver.findElement(By.css("ul#test li:nth-child(2) > div > span")).getText()
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  //ul[@id='test']//following::li[n]/div/span
  where, n = 2,3,4 etc.
  ```
- Effective line of code:

  ```
  await driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='test']//following::li[2]/div/span")).getText()
  ```

Comment: on both codes I got an erro: TypeError: d.driver.findElements(...).getText is not a function

Comment: @DragoJokera I'm not sure about _getText_ I took it from your code trials. I have removed it now.Please retest and let me know the status.

Comment: TypeError: By.cssSelector is not a function and for the xpath that it is not a legal expression

Comment: @DragoJokera Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I found the correct way: `const secondName = await d.driver.findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@id="test"]/li[2]/div/span`)).getText()`